# List delimiter with custom symbol

Tags: java, list, delimiter

I have list with some values:
 `List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1","2","3");`

I want convert it to String "1; 2; 3"

I have only idea with loop. It works but it doesn't looks elegant. Maybe somebody can advice more easy way to do it?

Comment: With Streams: `list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("; "))`. But `String::join` is probably more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `String.join("; ", list)`
It should work